# Macro to set custom follow-up flag for multiple emails

Tags: vba, microsoft-outlook-2016, flag

I found a code which I have been able to adapt to almost get me to where I want to; I want to be able to select multiple emails, then click a button to run a macro to set the flag follow up date to X days from now. How can I get this code to work for several selected emails?

```
Sub Set_3DaysFollowUp()

    Dim numDays As Double
    Dim uPrompt As String
    Dim MyMailItem As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set MyMailItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End If

    If (ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 1) And _
          (ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1).Class = olMail) Then

            Set MyMailItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)

    End If

    MyMailItem.TaskDueDate = Now + 3
    MyMailItem.FlagRequest = "Follow up"

    MyMailItem.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: You can go to Outlook for Developer forum for more information.

Comment: @Aidan, can you share a link to the forum? Can't find it.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?forum=outlookdev